# Javascript comparisons == null alternatives

Tags: javascript, jshint, triple-equals

In JavaScript code I want to replace the double-equals structure of the following if-statement:

```js
if( name == null ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

The double equals fail for the jshint rule "eqeqeq", where it's recommended to replace double equals with triple equals. For a moment, let's imagine the above code changed from `== null` to `=== null` like this:

```js
if( name === null ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

This would work for a variable explicitly defined having the value `null`, but unfortunately would fail for any unset variables like this.

```js
var a = null; // works correctly
var b;        // will fail in comparison
```

Previously when the triple-equals rule was important to me I would do the following

```
if( name === null ||| typeof(name) === 'undefined' )
```

but I find this extremely bloated.

The best alternative I can come up with now is to use the nature of the if-statement and let it evaluate to a false-ish expression like here where I negate the expression and simply remove the `== null` part:

```js
if( !name ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

For me, this is much simpler, easy to read, and completely avoids explicit equals comparison. However, I am uncertain if there are any edge causes I am missing out here?

So the question is, can I generally replace `== null` with the negated expression if statements? If so, what are the pitfalls and exceptions where it wouldn't work? Does it work for general array items, strings, object properties?

My criteria for picking a solution will be

- clean code
- easy to read and quickly understand
- validates jshint rules
- works in modern browsers (as of writing January 2015)

I am aware of other slightly related questions for discussing [difference in the equality operators `==` vs `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons), but this is merely for a discussion of the evaluation compared to null-ish inside the if-statement.

Comment: The `===` rule is *vastly* overrated, I'd probably just turn it off.

Comment: I like the `===` rule for one other reason: String comparison. Instead I think the strangest thing is that javascript originally introduced both `==` and  `===`. This leads to errors waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

> So the question is, can I generally replace == null with the negated expression if statements?

Probably not *universally*, no, but perhaps in some places.

> If so, what are the pitfalls and exceptions where it wouldn't work? Does it work for general array items, strings, object properties?

The `!value` check will be true for **all** of the falsey values, not just `null` and `undefined`. The full list is: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

So if you have `name = ""` then

```
if (!name) {
    // ...
}
```

...will evaluate true and go into the block, where your previous

```
if (name == null) {
    // ...
}
```

...would not. So just doing it everywhere is likely to introduce problems.

But for situations where you know that you do want to branch on any falsey value, the `!value` thing is very handy. For instance, if a variable is meant to be `undefined` (or `null`) or an object reference, I'll use `if (!obj)` to test that, because any falsey value is good enough for me there.

If you want to keep using JSHint's `===` rule, you could give yourself a utility function:

```
function isNullish(value) {
    return value === null || typeof value === "undefined";
}
```

The overhead of a function call is nothing to be *remotely* worried about ([more](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)), and any decent JavaScript engine will inline it anyway if it's in a hotspot.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I previously introduced the `isNullish`, but found that even though the behaviour is as expected, I can probably deal with the simpler way (given the constraints you are pointing out)